# convert parsed XML with nested child tag and missing child tags in container to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

My sample XML:

```
<RecordContainer RecordNumber = "1">
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <person>
         <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
         <personal_info>
            <age>40</age>
         </personal_info> 
      </person>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <description>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      </description>
      <details> 
          <info>this is the guide to XML</info>
      </details>
   </book>
 </catalog>
</RecordContainer>
<RecordContainer RecordNumber = "2">
 <catalog>  
   <book id="bk102">
      <person>
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      </person>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <description>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      </description>
   </book>
</catalog>
</RecordContainer>
```

Plase note that above XML has nested child tags and some of nested tags are missing in some of the containers.

My expected output is pandas dataframe with all the tags and fill null in case of any missing tag text.

code to parse the data:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

root = ET.fromstring("<root>"+ sample_data + "</root>")

records = []
containers = root.findall('.//RecordContainer')
for container in containers:
    entry = container.attrib
    book = container.find('.//catalog/book')
    entry.update(book.attrib)
    for child in list(book):
        entry[child.tag] = child.text
    records.append(entry)

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

Above code return null in case of missing tags and it is not aligned with the column name.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Surely you learned something from https://stackoverflow.com/q/58061959/407651?

Comment: @mzjn yes from the above I am able to process the earlier xml but as I have some missing nested tag in some of the container I am not able to process it

Comment: @hue please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061959/how-to-convert-parsed-xml-to-pandas-dataframe-or-csv-in-python ..

Comment: @balderman can you please also have a look at it

Comment: How is your code looking - please edit a [mre] into your question if you need help with it.

Comment: @barny I have updated my code in the question..

Comment: @JahnabKumarDeka This is a different xml (not like the one in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061959/how-to-convert-parsed-xml-to-pandas-dataframe-or-csv-in-python)  Try to adopt my solution to this xml

Comment: @balderman some change in the eariler XML is that it has nested tags and also some missing tags in different containers.